# Which thread owns RunWorkerCompleted?

Tags: c#, wpf

New to all this so…

If I start a BackgroundWorker from the main UI thread, I am successfully able to update my UI controls in the RunWorkerCompleted event of that same BackgroundWorker.  This part works great.

However, if I start a BackgroundWorker from a thread other than the UI thread, then I get an error in the RunWorkerCompleted method if I try to manipulate any UI controls.

My question: Is the thread that STARTS a BackgroundWorker the same thread that owns the RunWorkerCompleted method?  If so, is it possible to start a BackgroundWorker such that its associated RunWorkerCompleted method is on the UI thread?

(F.Y.I. I got around this problem by using a dispatcher inside the problematic RunWorkerCompleted method but I hoping there was another way. Thanks.)